# php file upload not working at all

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

Salutations, I am having problems allowing user's(admin) the ability to upload files/images to the server. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the part of my code where I am processing the file:

```
if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 20000))
    {
        if($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0)
        {
            header('Location: addAd.php?message='.$_FILES['image']['error'].'!');
        }
        else
        {
            if(file_exists('images/'.$_FILES['image']['name']))
            {
                header('Location: addAd.php?message=file already exists!');
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['temp_name'],'images/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
                $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: addAd.php?message=Invalid file!');
    }
```

And here is where I create the form:

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    for($i=1; $i<mysql_num_fields($rs); $i++)
    {
        $rsmd = mysql_fetch_field($rs,$i);
        if($rsmd->name == 'description')
        {
            echo '<textarea name="'.$rsmd->name.'" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea><br />';
        }
        else if($rsmd->name == 'image')
        {
            echo $rsmd->name.'<input type="file" name="'.$rsmd->name.'" /><br />';
        }
        else
        {
            echo $rsmd->name.'<input type="text" name="'.$rsmd->name.'" /><br />';
        }
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: What errors are being thrown?

Comment: Does `$rsmd->name` get printed (is it not empty)? Verify by looking at the HTML from your browser. Is the $_FILES array not empty upon posting? Put a `var_dump($_FILES)` on top of the code you posted. Also there's a few `if`'s in there, check that they get evaluated in the way you want. Besides all that (which is basic debugging), what _does_ happen? "Not working at all" isn't an error message.

Comment: $rsmd->name does return a value, and the var_dump is: 

    array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "422.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/php2VUtCl" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(23303) } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_FILES['image']['temp_name']` should be: `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'images/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't uploading. My folder permission is 755. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @user1090051 20000 bytes = 19.53125 kilobytes. Are you sure ? Tested and works in my computer.

Comment: I upped it to 40000, The file I am trying to upload is 23KB.

Comment: Actually Zulkhaery Basrul worked. My FTP program has problems updating. I typed in the full url to the image in my browser, and it was there. Thanks for your help.